# Array Combine Using String 'Keys' and Array 'Values'

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, key

I am attempting to use the array_combine function to combine a set of keys that are strings with a set of arrays. The array combine results in the new array being re-indexed.

```
$keys = array("00","11","22");
$values = array(0 => array("cake", "sprinkles"), 1 => array("dog", "cat"), 2 => array("water","fire"));

$combined_array = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cake
            [1] => sprinkles
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dog
            [1] => cat
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => water
            [1] => fire
        )
)
```

**Desired Result**

```
Array
(
    ["00"] => Array
        (
            [0] => cake
            [1] => sprinkles
        )

    ["11"] => Array
        (
            [0] => dog
            [1] => cat
        )

    ["22"] => Array
        (
            [0] => water
            [1] => fire
        )
)
```

Comment: `$Keys` => `$keys`. The code you've posted also doesn't result in your *RESULT* output - if you call `array_combine` with an invalid argument, it will just emit a warning and return false.

Comment: Sorry that's a error in the question, that isn't in the code, I'll ammend the post

Comment: The amended code works fine: https://eval.in/640940

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is fine

only typo error `$Keys` instead of `$keys`

```
$combined_array = array_combine($keys, $values);

echo "<pre>";print_r($combined_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [00] => Array
        (
            [0] => cake
            [1] => sprinkles
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => dog
            [1] => cat
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => water
            [1] => fire
        )

)
```

Also as commented how can you get output as you posted `array_combine` will through this `error`

> Warning:  array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: Yes you and @iaann are both right the amended example posted works fine an does get the desired result, this was being overwritten elsewhere in my actual project code which is why I had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try other  approach if this one doesn't work, i didn't try your code, but this is one of other solutions:

```
<?php

$keys = array("00","11","22");
$values = array(0 => array("cake", "sprinkles"), 1 => array("dog", "cat"), 2 => array("water","fire"));

foreach ($keys as $key) {
        foreach ($values as $k => $value) {

            $result[$key] = $value;
            // if you want to unset the initaial array
            // unset($values[$k]);

        }
}

var_dump($result); exit;

?>
```

Hope it helps.. 
Cheers